# Importing Scala .class files into MapForce

Tags: scala, map-force

Altova Mapforce allows user defined functions to be imported from Java `.class` files.  Since Scala also compiles to Java `.class` files, I figured I could use them interchangeably.  So I wrote some test objects and found I could import the `.class` files successfully but using some functions would fail always with

> java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: scala/*something*

For example, if compile the following file with `scalac`. I can import `Pass.class` and `Fail.class` with no issues

```
object Pass {
  def echo(s: String): String = s // no errors
}
object Fail {
  def greet(name: String): String = {
    // java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder
    "Hello, " + name 
  }  
}
```

Using `Pass.echo` works but `Fail.greet` raises the error, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder`.

My understanding is Mapforce is searching the Java libraries for Scala classes.  If that is correct then how can I tell MapForce to include Scala libraries?  Otherwise, what is the cause?

Comment: This is because your scala code relies on the scala standard library (just as it could rely on any other code) - I'm not familiar with Mapforce, but it should be possible to pass it the scala runtime jar for use in it's classpath.

Comment: @Lattyware would simply adding Scala to the environment variable be a better solution?

Comment: *`$env:CLASSPATH` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to pass the scala library to the applications classpath directly as Lattyware suggested but adding it to the global classpath allowed MapForce to use scala classes in the application.

```
PS C:\> echo $env:CLASSPATH
.;C:\Program Files\scala\lib;
```

I haven't tested how well that works with generating Java code.